# How to change URL dynamically in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm quite new at JQuery! I know how to change a button from Follow to Unfollow when clicked but **I need the url (in the button) to call my ResponseEntity in Spring and I do not know how to do it....**

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    button {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Follow' ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow');
            $('a').attr('href',($(this).text() == 'Follow' ? 'FollowUrl' : 'UnFollowUrl');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <button type="button">Follow</button><a href="/firsttime" id="url">Follow</a>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> HINT: Click the button to swap the text and the URL.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Click the button to swap the text and the URL"? What URL?

Answer (score 0):

Check the html that is generated on your page and change the javascript code depending on how it looks.

For example you can make 2 links (tag: ) toggle visibility like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //all <button>s on page that are clicked:
    $("button").click(function() {
      //Switch text on button.
      $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Follow' ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow');

      //Select all links (tag <a>) on page.
      $('a').toggle(); //toggle display: none/initial (visibility)
    });
  });
</script>

<!-- links that are going to be switched visibility -->
<a href="/follow" style="display:none;">follow</a>
<a href="/unfollow">unfollow</a>

<!-- button that has the event listener click in javascript code above -->
<button type="button">Follow</button>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Click the button to swap the text and the URL.</p>
```

Another option would be to replace the `href` attribute in the html tag:

```
// select element - change attr - chose attribute (href in this case) - set new value
$('YourSelectorHere').attr('href','NewLinkHere');
```

Comment: I prefer your second option but I can not make it work like a real toggle button, changing time and again. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: you'd have to add the same check: `$('YourSelectorHere').attr('href',($(this).text() == 'Follow' ? 'FollowUrl' : 'UnFollowUrl');`

Comment: Sorry, Joel I must be doing something wrong because it doesn't work. I edited the code in the question (script, button and href) to follow your instructions line by line. Thanks again.

Comment: @Miguel you could post the html of the generated page instead, i wonder how `<c:url var="follow" value="/follow" />` gets rendered into html?

Comment: They do not appear. I have take them out of the question, but it does not work with the a href (if I take it the h ref, the button toggles). Thxs

Comment: then add a link: `<a href="/follow>follow</a>` next to the button so there is one in the page to be swapped

Comment: I did, please see the edited question with the changes (I can not paste the code here), but still does not work and I do not see why..... button type="button" Follow /button  a href="/firsttime" id="url" Follow /a